# Restoring windows boot

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, grub, system-recovery

I recently reinstalled Fedora 35 on a dual-boot with Windows 10.
Unfortunately, I think I have accidentally formatted /boot/efi, as hints a `tree /boot`

```
/boot
├── config-5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64
├── config-5.14.16-301.fc35.x86_64
├── efi
│   ├── EFI
│   │   ├── BOOT
│   │   │   ├── BOOTIA32.EFI
│   │   │   ├── BOOTX64.EFI
│   │   │   ├── fbia32.efi
│   │   │   └── fbx64.efi
│   │   └── fedora
│   │       ├── BOOTIA32.CSV
│   │       ├── BOOTX64.CSV
│   │       ├── gcdia32.efi
│   │       ├── gcdx64.efi
│   │       ├── grub.cfg
│   │       ├── grubia32.efi
│   │       ├── grubx64.efi
│   │       ├── mmia32.efi
│   │       ├── mmx64.efi
│   │       ├── shim.efi
│   │       ├── shimia32.efi
│   │       └── shimx64.efi
│   ├── mach_kernel
│   └── System
│       └── Library
│           └── CoreServices
│               └── SystemVersion.plist
├── extlinux
│   ...
├── grub2
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── unicode.pf2
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   └── grubenv
├── initramfs-0-rescue-a26e1c2d27044f10ac613e4bc63e9612.img
├── initramfs-5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64.img
├── initramfs-5.14.16-301.fc35.x86_64.img
├── loader
│   └── entries
│       ├── a26e1c2d27044f10ac613e4bc63e9612-0-rescue.conf
│       ├── a26e1c2d27044f10ac613e4bc63e9612-5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64.conf
│       └── a26e1c2d27044f10ac613e4bc63e9612-5.14.16-301.fc35.x86_64.conf
├── lost+found
├── symvers-5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64.gz -> /lib/modules/5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64/symvers.gz
├── symvers-5.14.16-301.fc35.x86_64.gz -> /lib/modules/5.14.16-301.fc35.x86_64/symvers.gz
├── System.map-5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64
├── System.map-5.14.16-301.fc35.x86_64
├── vmlinuz-0-rescue-a26e1c2d27044f10ac613e4bc63e9612
├── vmlinuz-5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64
└── vmlinuz-5.14.16-301.fc35.x86_64
```

From my understanding, there should be windows appearing here.
The observed consequence is that windows does not appear in grub, and it is not possible to boot windows changing the BIOS priorities.

Here is what returns a `fdisk -l` with root access:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HBJQ-000L2              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5B49A787-6CFB-49B4-8F00-73B5F7F8A568

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296  473878527 473311232 225.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 998166528 1000214527   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environmen
/dev/nvme0n1p5 473878528  475975679   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 475975680  998166527 522190848   249G Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

From my understanding, I can use the windows recovery to try to fix the boot issue.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to boot from it.

I tried to press various keys at startup (Lenovo S540), as well as to change the boot order in the BIOS.

My questions are the following:

1. Do I have an easy way to access the windows recovery from my machine?
2. If not, how can I fix this issue?

EDIT:
Problem fixed. I created a Windows recovery device. The boot fix did not work natively, so I used the command prompt with

```
BOOTREC /FIXMBR
BOOTREC /FIXBOOT
BOOTREC /RebuildBcd
```

After that, windows still did not boot, but the automatic boot repair fixed everything.
To conclude, I just updated grub following Fedora guidelines, and I am not officially saved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Windows, and not *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you awhile ago. Heres the command I used in the Windows installer usb command prompt:
`Bcdboot C:\Windows /l en-us /s x: /f ALL`

Use `diskpart` to mount and unmount disks. Replace `C:\Windows` with your windows drives `Windows` folder and `x:` with your grub disk.